# CubeTextureLoader() not working. Or I'm doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

Here is my code:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.autoRotate = true;

// Cube
var Cubegeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const CubeImgTexture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().setPath('imgs/textures/cube/').load([
  's1.png', 's5.png',
  's2.png', 's4.png',
  's3.png', 's6.png'
]);
var Cubematerial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: CubeImgTexture
});
var CubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(Cubegeometry, Cubematerial);
scene.add(CubeMesh);

camera.position.z = 5;
controls.update();

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

When I run it, I get a blank screen and an error saying that "Argument 6 is not valid for any of the 6-argument overloads."

[image: Errors]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
var Cubematerial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: CubeImgTexture
});
```

You never initialize anything named `CubeImgTexture`. If you're trying to pass a cubeTexture into the `.map` property, you're going to run into problems because map [only expects a regular texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.map). Maybe you're trying to [assign it to the `.envMap` property instead?](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CubeTexture)